# Detect event from HTML to phaser

Tags: javascript, html, events, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

Actually I'm loading a HTML5 game using Phaser into a html file.
Phaser create a canvas where the game will be loaded

```
<body>
<div id="game-container">
  <div class="font-preload">
    <div style="font-family: majalla;" class="arial">.</div>
    <div style="font-family: Metropolitain;" class="arial">.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="dev-info">
    <p class="frames">--</p>
    <p class="build"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
     <button  onclick="onclickButton()">
  </div>
  <canvas style...... here the game will be loaded
</div>
```

I would like to dispatch an event from button to my game to simulate a button PLAY action, this is a function is inside my game, it's possible?

I would like to acces a function inside my game, inside the canvas. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer

All my Events/Signals are defined in Phaser.state.

I can acces to my context using this

- globalContext = Phaser.GAMES[0].state.callbackContext;

In this globalContext I can dispatch a signal:

- globalContext.onButtonPlayClick.dispatch();

And is this, the game loaded in the canvas recived this signal all do the play action

Thanks specially for Prerak Acharya for his interest